# How to make play a sound from a string?

Tags: python

I am trying to play a sound that is a string such as 'hello world'.

I am able to create a local mp3 player and then play it, however, I dont want to save the mp3 player locally.

here is the code that allows me to save and play an mp3, specifically the function speak::

```
from gtts import gTTS
import playsound
import numpy as np

from constants.greetings import greetings


from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play
from gtts import gTTS
import pygame




class OutputSoundHandler:
    def __init__(self, openai_api):
        self.openai_api = openai_api
        self.greetings =  [ "How can I help", "Ahoy there, Captain!", "Bonjour, Master!"]

    def get_greeting(self):
        return np.random.choice(self.greetings)

    def speak(self, text):
        tts = gTTS(text=text, lang='en')
        tts.save('response.mp3')
        playsound.playsound('response.mp3', True)
```

is there a way to do this without saving the mp3 locally?

I tried asking chatgpt but it was not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [docs](https://gtts.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), there is a [stream()](https://gtts.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/gtts/tts.html#gTTS.stream) function.

You can store the stream as a bytes, and then use `AudioSegment.from_file`, passing it the bytes instead of a filename.

```py
from pydub.playback import play
from pydub import AudioSegment
from gtts import gTTS
from io import BytesIO

# Generate the audio
tts = gTTS(text='Hello, world', lang='en')

# Save the bytes to a file-like object
mp3_as_bytes = next(tts.stream())

# Play the audio
audio = AudioSegment.from_file(BytesIO(mp3_as_bytes), format="mp3")
play(audio)
```

You need to use `BytesIO(mp3_as_bytes)` because of null-bytes, which can throw a ValueError.